# Drupal 7.43 and Solr 5.5 Search API - Can’t Add Fields to Index

Tags: php, solr, drupal-7, solr-search

I am not an expert in drupal or solr, it’s a production legacy product that we are trying to upkeep, and we are having an issue that for the life of me I can’t figure out and I need some help.

We are using the Apache Solr Search API module and have an index configured in Drupal. In there we can add fields, and then, choose which of the fields to index. And then things index just fine.

The issue at hand is that we scroll to the bottom and choose to add more fields, select the entity, say, Students, or Scientists, or Doctors - each of which has properties. Generally we just select one of those and click add fields and they add successfully and they appear on the list of fields. Then we choose the field we care about from the list and checkbox it for indexing. Well, the issue at hand is that th is particular drupal instance says “fields added successfully” but then, they’re not there. It’s not truly adding them.

If I restore this particular drupal production instance from backup to my local drupal, things work fine. I can add fields.

I tried clearing the caches, no dice.

I tried to create a new index configuration in the search api, and it adds and I can add fields just fine. I just can’t add fields in the default one.

I also tried a new solr core, no dice. But I don’t think the issue is from the solr end, it’s from the drupal end in the index configuration, before indexes are performed and sent to the solr core.

There are no errors, no logs. It just says they added successfully, but there’s nothing new in the list.

Any ideas?

I’ve thought of rebuilding permissions within drupal, but I don’t want to try this in production. I’d like to get a fix in place based on knowledge not guessing.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. The solution ended up being updating `max_input_vars` in `php.ini` or `php_value max_input_vars` in the `.htaccess` file to `10000` from `1000`